# How can I link libm to my emscripten port

Tags: hyperlink, emscripten, libm

I am trying to use emscripten to port some C code that requires `libm`. Usually, it uses my system's version, and I don't need to worry about linking to it, but I need to manually link it with emscripten.

**How can I link `libm`?**

I have tried using [`openlibm`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm), but when I `make` it with `emcc` (the emscripten compiler) it cannot find all dependencies, as `openlibm` still depends on system headers.

I have also tried using the GNU `libc` source, but cannot navigate those `Makefile`s.

What I need is the bitcode, as generated by `emcc`, to link to when compiling to JavaScript, using the `-lm` flag in the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`libm` is linked by default.**

The `emcc` compiler will not be able to link it if it is specified (as `-lm`), as this requires an explicit search path (with `-L/path/`). It has an internal implementation which should not be overwritten, unless you can supply your own `emcc`-compiled bitcode.

The compiler will throw warnings for the unresolved library until you compile to JavaScript, as `libm` is not included until the final compile. These errors on the intermediate targets can and should be ignored - it is a known issue.

The available libraries through the compiler can be found at https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include. Specifically, `libm` is included in the [`musl` headers](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include/libc). It is not explicit, but that is covered in the `musl` FAQs.